# Tooltips not showing up on Ubuntu using PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, pyqt, tooltip

I'm getting started with PyQt4 and tested the following code...

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Tooltip(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltip')

        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('OldEnglish', 10))


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
tooltip = Tooltip()
tooltip.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, no tooltip shows up! I'm on Ubuntu 10.04. I also tried an icon and that didn't work either.

Comment: I ran your code on Windows (albeit with PySide rather than PyQt) and the tooltip does appear. I know that doesn't really help you, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: tested your code on my 10.04 LTS and "This is a Qwidget widget" tooltip is showing up

Comment: Make sure that the window is active by clicking on it (or its decorations) first.

Answer (score 2):

If the window you start your application from ( e.g. your terminal ) is active, hovering over your application will not show a Tooltip. As Ivo indicated you need to make the window of your application active for the Tooltips to show up.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but how would I make the window active?

Comment: @J-Win E.g. normally by clicking anywhere on the window. But if you are not sure if it is not already active, click somehwere on the (top) border, so you don't by chance start some functionality.

Comment: Interesting. The tool tip is still not showing up. I'm using the same code as posted in the question above. Any ideas?

Comment: @J-Win Sorry no. I haven't used this kind of stuff for some time now. You are probably not running Ubuntu 10.04 (because it is EOL), I am not sure if more modern desktops still support that functionality in the same way. Maybe you should be using PyQT5?